# Creating multiple metafields with different key showing Error

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, shopify

I want to Create multiple Meta fields with different key but it displaying me following error:

> 'metafield' => 'expected Array to be a Hash',

This is my code:

```
    $prodcut_variant = array(

    'metafield'=>array(
       array('namespace'=>'orbital_response',
             'key'=>'Os Purchases',
             'value'=>'0',
             'value_type'=>integer,),
       array('namespace'=>'orbital_response',
             'key'=>'Stock Status',
             'value'=>'C',
             'value_type'=>integer,)

));

$request_update = $shopify('POST /admin/products/{#ID}/metafields.json',array(),$prodcut_variant);
```

Comment: I don’t see it saying anywhere in the docs that you can pass an array of arrays … all the examples I see just pass a single-level array with the four named properties.

Comment: But I want to add multiple keys

Comment: Well have you tried adding them one at a time?

Comment: yes I want to add with one request

Comment: Well then go check the docs for whether there is a syntax that males this possible.

Comment: ok wil check thanks

Comment: try `'metafields'=>` instead of `'metafield'=>` also, are you sure `array('namespace'=>'orbital_response',
             'key'=>'Stock Status',
             'value'=>'C',
             'value_type'=>integer,)
` is being passed as a JSON object?

Comment: Also error in metafileds

Comment: 'metafield' => 'Required parameter missing or invalid'

Comment: It does not appear that the API allows multiple metafields to be added with a single request. From the Docs: "POST /admin/products/{#ID}/metafields.json - Create a new metafield for a product"

Comment: I tried this when I was building a custom metafield app, but couldn't push multiply arrays. So I don't think that this is possible, but I may be mistaken, since I didn't spend too much time looking into this then.

Comment: It's only working with single metafield array at time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding metafields with a new record you can pass an array of metafields. Otherwise you have to create them one at a time at the url '/admin/variant/#id/metafields.json

Your value 'C' is not an integer. I suspect the quoted '0' won't go through either. It is likely these that are throwing the first error. Do you mean 0 or 0xC?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from key

```
'value_type'=>integer,),
```

like as

```
'value_type'=>integer),
```